# Different enums, same value

Tags: c++, enumeration

Is it possible to make two different enums with a same value?
For example,

```
enum direction{
    LEFT,
    RIGHT,
    UP,
    DOWN,
    NONE
}
enum color{
   RED,
   GREEN,
   BLUE,
   NONE
}
```

The compiler would say that there are two declarations of 'NONE'.
Is there a way around this?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There's a couple ways around this.  One way is to use namespaces to wrap enums and prevent the values from polluting the global namespace:

```
namespace direction {
    enum direction {
        LEFT,
        RIGHT,
        UP,
        DOWN,
        NONE
    };
}
namespace color {
    enum color {
       RED,
       GREEN,
       BLUE,
       NONE
    };
}
```

You can also use the new C++11 way (if your compiler supports it) and use "strongly-typed enums"

```
enum class direction {
    LEFT,
    RIGHT,
    UP,
    DOWN,
    NONE
};
enum class color {
   RED,
   GREEN,
   BLUE,
   NONE
};
```

Both can be used by the syntax `direction::NONE` or `color::NONE` but there is one major difference.  In the first case the enums will still implicitly cast to ints.  This means you can write

`int foo = direction::NONE;`

and everything is fine.

In the second case, this would be a compiler error since foo is not the same type as direction.  You can get around this by doing

`direction foo = direction::NONE;`

which may or may not work for you.  If you need to cast it to an int, you are welcome to use `static_cast<int>(foo)` to get an integer type.

Comment: Thanks, the first method seems more efficient for what i'm making right now, so i'll stick to it.